# Bash, find and replace - re-use with variable?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm building a script in bash that goes and finds references to other files (such as a reference in an html file to an img source (image.jpg)

The problem is that I'm using sed to replace all instances that contain (in this example) **"/some/random/directory/image.jpg"**

The **"some/random/directory/image.jpg"** is going to be differen every single time so when it comes to my sed line I need to use regex, but in order to find the line to replace I need to include **image.jpg**.

so for example my sed line would be something like

```
sed 's/\/some\/random\/directory\/image.jpg/images\/image.jpg/g'
```

But how do I get the end of whats in the find and put it into the replace? (In this example it would be **image.jpg**.  Is there some way to make that a variable?

Here's my script as it stands now:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/username/www/immrqbe/

for file in $(grep -rlI ".jpg" *)
do
sed -e "s/\".*\/.*.jpg//ig" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp
mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp /home/username/www/immrqbe/$file
done
```

This obviously isn't functional complete as I need help with it but you get the idea of how I'd like to have it complete.

Comment: For ease-of-reading, remember that sed can use other characters than `/` as a delimiter.  Thus, your initial sed script could be: `sed 's:/some/random/directory/image.jpg:images/image.jpg:g'`

Comment: oh, nice! I never knew that, thanks much!

Comment: As a side note: Never do this: for x in $(command) or `command` or $var. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. *.txt), arrays (eg. "${names[@]}") or a while-read 
                loop (eg. while read -r line). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, and don't forget to double-quote every expansion, i.e. "$file" instead of $file in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a ***Backreference*** in the world of regular expressions.  You want to *refer back* to a previously matched string.

There are a couple of ways to do this with sed, but what you want to use is the grouping mechanism: `\(` and `\)`.  Anything sed finds between `\(` and `\)` will be put into a group and you can refer back to that group using `\n` where `n` is the number of the group that you want to use, from left to right.

So, in your example, you want:

```
sed 's/".*\/\(.\+\.jpg\)"/\1/ig' file
```

Your filename will be in the `\(.\+\.jpg\)` group and you can then refer to it using `\1` in the replacement section.

---

As a side note, notice that, as long as you don't want the shell to expand a variable in your quoted string, you can use single quotes and avoid escaping the double quotes in your pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the education! I'll work with this and report back and mark solved once I get it all working ok (as soon as I have time).

Answer (score 3):

Use parentheses to capture the match and then refer to it using backslash.

```
sed -e 's/".*\/\(.*.jpg\)/\1/ig'
```